# Use Firebase storage downloadURL to display image

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm working on a Vue project and I want to display images that are stored in Firebase Storage. However, when I put in the downloadURL of an image in a HTML img tag for the source, it doesn't display. Is there a step in between or do I have to change the rules?

img tag result:
[image]

img source:
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/vueauth-9e069.appspot.com/o/user-uploads%2Fimages%2FGitHub-Mark.png?alt=media&token=55ca40dd-58af-46b9-8e7a-1cead6d9c031

Firebase storage rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Download URLs are not affected by security rules at all.  Anyone with a download URL can use it.  Something else is wrong, but we can't see what that is.

Comment: @Andriy please refer to this solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62117593/2731312