# Finding image based on file name firebase storage React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am currently trying to display an image with a map function that goes through a document in my firestore. My firestore document looks like this:

[image]

and I have a photo in my firebase storage with the same name as the photo id.

[image]

I am planning to use

```
const ref = firebase.storage().ref(item.photoid);
const url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
```

with

```
renderAccordion() {
    return this.state.accordionarr.map((item,index) => {
      return(
        <View key={index}>
          <Accordion
            onChange={this.onChange}    
            activeSections={this.state.activeSections}
            >
            <Accordion.Panel header= {item.name}>
              <List>
                <List.Item>{item.protein}</List.Item>
                <List.Item>{item.carbohydrate}</List.Item>
              </List>
            </Accordion.Panel>
          </Accordion>          
        </View>
      );
    });
  }
```

to show the image. However, in order to have "await" I have to make renderAccordion() an async function. But, when I do that, I received an "invariant violation objects are not valid as a react child" error. What is a way to retrieve the image based on my document field of photoid and successfully display it on the screen?

EDIT: I've added a function to set state of each one of my photos

```
renderAccordion() {
    return this.state.accordionarr.map((item,index) => {
      let fetchImage
      firebase
      .storage()
      .ref(item.photoid)
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then((url) => {
        let state = {};
        state[item.photoid] = url
        this.setState(state)
      });
      return(
        <View key={index}>
          <Accordion
            onChange={this.onChange}    
            activeSections={this.state.activeSections}
            >
            <Accordion.Panel header= {item.name}>
              <List>
                <List.Item>
                  <Image
                  style = {styles.sizer}
                  source = {{uri: this.state[item.photoid]}}
                  />
                </List.Item>
                <List.Item>{item.protein}</List.Item>
                <List.Item>{item.carbohydrate}</List.Item>
              </List>
            </Accordion.Panel>
          </Accordion>          
        </View>
      );
    });
  }
```

But, now I received an error message that only says [object Object]. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is unclear how the two snippets you shared are related. But either way: if something is loaded asynchronously you'll need to store it in the state (either by calling `setState` or using the state hook). See my answer here for examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61192087, https://stackoverflow.com/a/52836403

Comment: I've tried the solution in the second link: let fetchImage
      firebase
      .storage()
      .ref(item.photoid)
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then((url) => {
        let state = {};
        state[item.photoid+"_url"] = url
        this.setState(state)
      }); But I am receiving and error message that only says [object Object]. Did I miss something?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the updated code and error message.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've made my changes! Thanks for helping me out, I really appreciate it.

Comment: to inspect the object could you use `JSON.stringify` to print it, this is to be able to see the object structure and values instead of only seeing that it is an object.